# How to keep my node js endpoints safe and to be accessible only from my website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

### I have endpoints coded in `Nodejs`... I use the following codes to keep them safe...

```
const corsOption = {
    origin: ['https://www.mywebsite.com'],
};
app.use(cors(corsOption));
```

---

```
if (host !== "myendpoint.com") {
  return res.status(403).json({ message: "forbidden access" });
}
```

---

will these keep my endpoints safe... or do I have to do anything more for my endpoints to keep them safe... I don't want bots or anyone else to use it... I know that they are public but I want to restrict access... pls, any help or suggestion ???

thank you

Comment: "*they are public but i want to restrict access*" - that sounds like a conflicting requirement. To **whom** do you want to restrict access?

Comment: What is the point of `host !== "myendpoint.com"`?

Comment: hi @bergi... thanks... what i mean is that... not accessible from "postman", "insomnia"... any bots... like such

Comment: @Bergi... when i used "req.get('host')" it gave the name of my "google functions url name"... so i wrote it there

Comment: That is not possible. A public web service is public and does not discriminate between clients. Just take it offline if you don't want anyone to access it.

Comment: Hi Ashish. Alot of people put an Nginx server in front of the backend Node.js application servers as a security measure.

Comment: Your question title says "*from my website*", but it's not clear what you mean by that. It doesn't (and shouldn't) matter to the server whether a website is visited using a browser like Firefox or Chrome or Postman or something else.

Comment: @RonnieRoyston how does nginx improve security?

Comment: @RonnieRoyston nginx is not a security measure. There are other (good) reasons why to put it there, but security is not one of them.

Comment: Nginx documentation on security controls https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/

Comment: @Bergi... i used this code... and restricted access from postman... if (host !== "***.***") {
        return res.status(403).json({ message: "unauthorized access" });
    }...

Comment: CORS is a mechanism for lifting some of the SOP's restrictions. The SOP is enforced by browsers, but not by all user agents (like curl, Postman, etc.); as such, the SOP (or CORS, for that matter) is no substitute for server-side authorisation.

Answer (score 1):

To be sure you can control who can access your endpoint, you can setup a token authentication.
When you send a request to your endpoint, the header should include:

`Authorization: Token {your token}`

And in your endpoint, you can check if the token is authorized or not (by storing authorized token in a database). If the token is not recognized, you can send back a 403 error.

Comment: thankds @Eloi... but will this be sufficient ???

Comment: To the question: will this be sufficient? Nothing is sufficient in cybersecurity. But you can add layers of security like using your method and mine and I guess it will be enough for your purpose.

Comment: thanks @Eloi... i will do it

Answer (score 1):

If your website accesses your endpoints, this means that *any browser* that can display your website must also be able to access your endpoints. Requests are not made *by your website*, they are made *by browsers visiting your website*.

You must first ask how much you want to restrict access:

- Restrict to individual known users to whom you send a password via mail, which they must then type into your website ("log on") before they can make any requests to your endpoints.
- Restrict to users who have self-registered. Can anyone in the world then self-register, or do you demand confirmation via an email address?
- Restrict to users who can log on with their Google (or Facebook, or ...) account.

Zain_Ul_Din's answer shows details of a possible implementation for the "self-registration" case. See also [What's the best way to add social login (Sign in with Google) to existing email/password app and database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72554502)

Answer (score -1):

you can implement user authentication and authorization in your Node js app to restrict access.
for this you can use the `jsonwebtoken` npm package.

Look up John Smilga's node and express projects on google for a 10hr video including 4 projects. One of the projects introduces JSON web tokens and how to use them.I highly recommend that.

You can also use the `express-rate-limit` package. With this you should be able to 'limit' how many requests a user can make to your API endpoints within a set amount of time. If the requests exceed that limit then this middleware steps in and stops further access (Haven't tested it in production myself but looks good)

Comment: thanks @Kashaan... i use firebase... and m successfully able to authenticate and authorize my user with jwet... "express-rate-limit" i read somewhere is annoying for user and should not be used... i just want my endpoints not to be used from anywhere other than my website