# How to hide secret keys in React.js application (frontend side)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web-frontend

I am trying to hide a secret key in a React frontend application. I know it's not a good idea, but I don't have the choice.

In fact I want my frontend application to be the only thing that send request to my backend application and I thought it's a good idea to have a secret key to send it in the backend side this way I'm sure that it a legitimate request and allow it.

I tried `.env` but it doesn't work.

Comment: You cannot hide secrets on Frontend. Any frontend code can be reverse engineered. You could probably use https only cookies to give your users some kind of token.

Comment: Does that help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74964584/16462950

Answer (score -1):

**CORS** restricting access for only specific domain on the backend. E.g in Nodejs express:

```
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors({
  origin: ['http://example.com', 'http://example2.com'],
}))
```

For more security, we can implement asymmetric encryption feature like RSA encryption.

Comment: @hungtan273 this solution can only works for a request that had made via a browser, it's could easily be bypassed by a curl request or postman

Comment: Of course, if you need that level of security then use asymmetric encryption